# WIn7 & Ubuntu fail, replaced RAM, now error no. 5 while installing ubuntu, XP install fails & win 7 BSODs

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows, hardware, ram

I had a dual boot system with Windows 7 and Ubuntu, everything was fine, but recently something went wrong, both the os began to hang, then the system was completely dead. I had to change the ram / ddr3 2GB.

The system was alive, but I began having problems, windows XP installation  was unsuccessful after many attempts, windows 7 install crashed a few times, but it was completed, however it keeps crashing again and again with a blue screen, and I am still unable to install Ubuntu after many tries, it keeps giving error no, 5 .......... try moving to coooler..?

I thougt it was the hard disk / sata 160 gb, I wiped everything with fdisk,  and repartitioned, did scandisk etc, but still no luck,  could it be the ram  ... the board is zebronics g41.

Comment: I don't know the specific error description, but based on my personal experience I think your hard drive is physically failing, and no amount of formatting/repartitioning is going to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you create a LiveUSB installation of Ubuntu with [persistence](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence) (read that link) then reboot with it. Once you have done so, then open up a terminal window and run the [smartmontools test](http://blog.shadypixel.com/monitoring-hard-drive-health-on-linux-with-smartmontools/) with

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
```

and then (assuming your hard drive is /dev/sda - and change the following line if not) run

```
sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda
sudo smartctl -s on -o on -S on /dev/sda
```

to turn on offline data collection and then do

```
sudo smartctl -H /dev/sda
```

and if it fails, your hard drive is bad & needs replacement. If not, do an overnight

```
sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sda
```

for a very rigorous test.  Please click on edit above on the left to post any results - and it's OK if the post gets long.